# Is this a free context gramar language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, automata

Is this a context free language?

> `{a^(2k) b^n c^n : k >= 0 ∧ 0 <= n <= m}` ∪
>   `{a^(2k+1) b^n c^m :k >= 0 ∧ n >= m >= 0}`

Comment: Yes it is.  Try finding a grammar for each part and seeing how to combine them together.

Comment: I have an exam tomorrow and I need to solve this exercise. I dont know how to find the grammar. thank you

Comment: @RoxeeMan I think question is `{a^(2k) b^n c^m : k >= 0 ∧ 0 <= n <= m} ∪ {a^(2k+1) b^n c^m :k >= 0 ∧ n >= m >= 0}` you have `a^(2k) b^n c^n` before `U` operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove a Language a Context-Free-Language is to write Context-Free-Grammar for the given language:(or either draw PDA)

The language below:

> {a<sup>(2k)</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>m</sup>    : k >= 0 and 0 <= n <= m} U
>   {a<sup>(2k+1)</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>m</sup>  : k >= 0 and n >= m >= 0}

is Context Free Language

<sub>*I think you have made mistake in writing question as I commented to you question*, I am doing for above grammar</sub>

We can write Context-Free-Grammar for this Language:

in Context-Free-Grammar productions of kind `α --> β` where `α` is a single variable.

> S --> S<sub>1</sub> | S<sub>2</sub>

S<sub>1</sub> generates this part {a<sup>(2k)</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>m</sup>    : k >= 0 and 0 <= n <= m} and S<sub>2</sub>  generates {a<sup>(2k+1)</sup> b<sup>n</sup> c<sup>m</sup>  : k >= 0 and n >= m >= 0}

> S<sub>1</sub> --> AB
>
> A   --> Aaa | ^
>
> B   --> bBc | ^
>
> B   --> Bc

And

> S<sub>2</sub> --> AaC
>
> C   --> bCc | ^
>
> C   --> bC

In grammar `S` is start Variable and {S, S<sub>1</sub>, S<sub>2</sub>, A, B, C} all are variable.
So in above grammar every productions are in the form `α --> β` where `α` is a single variable hence given language is Context-Free-Language.

<sub>Let me know if you have other doubt or *if your language I misunderstood*</sub>